# three.js: how to apply alpha-map when using OBJMTL loader?

Tags: three.js, textures

Actually I am trying to upload these .obj and .mtl file by OBJMTLloader. all is working fine but the image in mtl file is loaded by map_d is not uploaded.

newmtl Eyelashes

```
Ns 10.0000
Ni 1.5000
d 0.5000
Tr 0.0000
Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
illum 2
Ka 0.5880 0.5880 0.5880
Kd 0.5880 0.5880 0.5880
Ks 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000

map_Ka EyelashesDiffuseTexture.jpg
map_Kd EyelashesDiffuseTexture.jpg
map_d EyeLashes_Opacity_Texture.jpg
```

My code is

```
 var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
   loader.load( 'upload/model.obj', 'upload/model.mtl', function ( object ) {
                                        object.position.y = -35;
                                        scene.add( object );
                                } ); 
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }
function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }
```

What i need to change in my code.
I try so may example and checked so many answers but not get helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply!! So Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Now i do this. you are right i use alpha-channel for it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three.js does not support alpha-maps in any of its materials.

The work-around is to bake the alpha-map into the alpha-channel of the diffuse map.

three.js r.66

Answer (score 1):

Now three.js supports alpha maps. But you need change MTLLoaded.js. Add to `createMaterial_`

```
case 'map_d':
    // Alpha texture map
    params[ 'alphaMap' ] = this.loadTexture( this.baseUrl + value );
    params[ 'transparent' ] = true;

    break;
```

three.js r.74